# jest mock a property that is an object and a function at the same time

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, nock

I am trying to mock a property of an object that acts as an object and as a function at the same time. Here's the code:

index.js

```
const nock = require('nock');

async function myFunc() {
  nock.back.setMode('param1');
  const { nockDone } = await nock.back('param1', 'param2');
  nock.enableNetConnect('param1');
  return nockDone;
}

module.exports = { myFunc }
```

My goal is to mock the nock object in a way I can assert that when `myFunc` is called, `nock.back` is called with param1 and param2.

To do so I have the following test:

index.test.js

```
const nock = require('nock');
const subjectUnderTest = require('./index');

const nockBackImplementation = jest.fn();
nockBackImplementation.setMode = jest.fn();

const nockBackMock = jest.spyOn(nock, 'back');
nockBackMock.mockImplementation(() => nockBackImplementation);

describe('test', () => {
  it('calls nock.back with the proper parameters', () => {
    subjectUnderTest.myFunc();

    expect(nockBackMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('param1', 'param2');
  });
});
```

For some reason, the test fails saying that the mock function has not been called and also gives this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: nock.back.setMode is not a function
```

I'm not sure how to properly mock `nock`.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? I'm having a very similar issue...

Comment: me too @NickMeldrum

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the setMode mock to the function used as implementation, which I think is different from the actual `nock.back` mock. You can set it correctly this way

```
const nockBackMock = jest
  .spyOn(nock, "back")
  .mockResolvedValue({ nockDone: "test" });
nockBackMock.setMode = jest.fn();
// you also need to mock the enableNetConnect to avoid errors
const enableNetConnectMock = jest
  .spyOn(nock, "enableNetConnect")
  .mockReturnValue({});

describe("test", () => {
  it("calls nock.back with the proper parameters", () => {
    subjectUnderTest.myFunc();

    expect(nockBackMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith("param1", "param2");
  });
});
```